# Enabling the SHOP Button from form2 closing event

Tags: c#

I have a little problem that I can't enable the shop button when the form2 closes.

So, I was making a shop for my clicker game. When you press the SHOP button your given a form2 (which was supposed to be the shop, WIP) and the shop button (button2) should be disabled because you can spam the shop button when its not disabled. After closing the shop the button was supposed to be enabled again, but I can't get it to work.

Note: the Form 2 Close button for the shop is sCloseBtn.

Form 1 Code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i += 1;
        if (i == 1)
        {
            label4.Text = "Cake";
        }
        else
        {
            label4.Text = "Cakes";
        }

        label3.Text = Convert.ToString(i);

    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowsFormsApplications2.Form2 secondForm;
        secondForm = new WindowsFormsApplications2.Form2();

        if (isInGui == false) {
            secondForm.Show();
            button2.Enabled = false;
            isInGui = true;
        }
        else if (isInGui == true)
        {
            button2.Enabled = true;
            isInGui = false;
        }
       }
```

Form 2 Code:

```
 private void sCloseBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: Make `button2` field public.

Comment: by field you mean make button2_Click public? That is already done. And I tried making button2.Enabled = true; public, that gives me an error. I get no errors when I try to enable the button2 in form2Closing event. But it doesn't work for some odd reason.

Comment: Because you can't access `Form1` in `Form2` directly because it is null, you should define a prop for From2 like `public Form1 Form1{get;set;}` and when you opening `Form2` you should initiate that prop like `secondForm.Form1 = this;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve that would be to move the event handler "Form2_FormClosing" to Form1,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // ...whatever is in your form already...

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        button2.Enabled = true;
        isInGui = false;
    }

    // ...
}
```

and to assign it to secondForm's event after its creation, ie.

```
secondForm = new WindowsFormsApplications2.Form2();
secondForm.FormClosing += Form2_FormClosing;
```